# Why does docker container exiting by itself

Tags: dockerfile

I want to build and run docker container for go file.

When I run the docker with the following command:

```
$ docker run -d -p 80:80 hello-app
1f6e5787890527b045e6ef417f2ab0662ce35b7bad5418df21c19fac5b0cb465
```

If I then go to http://localhost:80 , it does not work.

If I go to my host machine and execute `docker ps`, it is empty

If I go to my host machine and execute `docker ps -a`, I get:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
1f6e57878905        hello-app           "go-wrapper run"    2 minutes ago       Exited (2) 2 minutes ago                       zealous_feistel
```

I see my container is here. It s mean When I run some container , it is rendering and then closing.
Why docker container is exiting by itself and not working ?

And here is my main.go

```
package main
import (
    "net/http"
    "io"
)
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("", index)
    http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil)
}

func index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    io.WriteString(w, "hello from docker")
}
```

And DockerFile ;

```
FROM golang:1.8-onbuild
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you show your `Dockerfile`. Depending on what you have your `CMD/ENTRYPOINT` set to, you may be able to get things working with: `docker run -it -d -p 80:80 hello-app`

Comment: My  **Dockerfile** is include just   `FROM golang:1.8-onbuild` and I tried `docker run -it -d -p 80:80 hello-app`  It's not working.

Comment: Your `Dockerfile` lacks the commands to transfer your `main.go` to the container. It also lacks the execution of said script. I would recommend you learn docker basics.

Comment: Are you sure , because I m trying to learn docker and  I wathcing this guy and the same code and same file working for him  [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UtNeLfXaBJM)

Comment: Yes, I am pretty sure. Think about it, docker containers are isolated containers. How is your `main.go` going to make its way into the container? You have to tell it via the `Dockerfile`, specifically, via the `ADD` command. Something like `ADD main.go` (assuming your `main.go` is in the same directory as your `Dockerfile`). After that you then have to tell the container to run the go script... how else will it know?

Comment: Thank you for your interest. You are right. I will read more about docker and will do this job. I will follow your advice.

Answer (score 0):

docker container exits as soon as the main process in the container exits. You can see this in the `docker ps` output -   `Exited (2) 2 minutes ago`

Your hello-app is not listening for connections on port 80 but it is exiting as soon as it starts.